# illustrator moving objects using arrow keys

Tags: adobe-illustrator, arrow-keys

When i try to move an object in Adobe illustrator it gets moved by about 20 pixels instead of just 1 pixel. I normally use the arrow keys to move objects as i find it easy lining up items. I changed the art board settings but that did not help.

Comment: Can i set the amount an object is moved by when using the arrow keys?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with programming.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From helpx.adobe.com:

The distance the object moves each time you press an arrow key is determined by the Keyboard Increment preference. The default distance is 1 point (1/72 of an inch, or .3528 millimeter). To change the Keyboard Increment preference, choose Edit > Preferences > General (Windows) or Illustrator > Preferences > General (Mac OS).

Answer (score 9):

It's also important to make sure that View > Snap To Grid is turned off. That has caused me some problems with the nudging using the arrow keys being inconsistent in illustrator.

Comment: This appears to be a comment rather than an answer to the question.

Comment: And `Snap to Pixel`, which forces an object to have integer coordinates, shall also be disabled.